# Change theme of listview split button

Tags: jquery, listview, jquery-mobile, mobile

I'm trying very hard to fix this can anyone help. What I'm after is when the job is added to a fav list the icon on the right of a split listview will go yellow or whatever. See my code...

```
//Add some global vars
jobid_fav = '';

//console.log(user_id);
$('.favs').click(function (e) {
    //$(this).attr("data-theme", "e");//.removeClass("ui-btn-up-c").addClass("ui-btn-up-e");
    jobid_fav = $(this).parent().attr('data-name');
    $('#addtofav').popup("open");
});

//Add the job ID to the user favourite list
$('#yesfav').click(function (e) {
    var uid = $('#userid').val();
    if (uid) {
        addToFavourites(jobid_fav, uid);
    } else {
        //Send user to login
         $.mobile.changePage( "login.php", { transition: "slideup"} );
    }
    $('#addtofav').popup("close");
});

//Bail out
$('#nofav').click(function(e){
    $('a [data-name='+ jobid_fav + ']').attr("data-theme", "e");
    //console.log($('a [data-name='+ jobid_fav + ']'));
    $('#addtofav').popup("close");
});
```

You can see I have tried a few things and many many more! The link to the site is http://www.employmenow.co.uk/web/m

The yesfav and nofav are button clicks from the popup window.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Rob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, jQuery Mobile isn't reacting to `.listview("option", "splitTheme", "e")` to change theme of split button. Therefore, the only way is to do it manually by adding `ui-btn-up-e` class to `span` with class `ui-btn` which is a child of the split button.

I've add `fav` class to split buttons in order to store them in a variable and call them later.

```
// var to store object
var split_btn = "";

// save object of clicked split button
$(".fav").on("click", function () {
    split_btn = $(this);
});

// popup buttons, if yes, remove old theme and add new one
$("#yes").on("click", function () {
    split_btn.find("span.ui-btn").toggleClass("ui-btn-up-c ui-btn-up-e");
    $("#popup").popup("close");
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/9Yj5K/)**